# Need help creating a large sample in Rstudio

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio

Q1.2 Create synthetic sample
Create a synthetic sample using the size of 404,638 where 67.8% of the released prisoners are coded with a 1 and the rest are coded as 0.
1.3 Create a bootstrap sampling distribution
Create a bootstrap sampling distribution by bootstrapping the sample using 1000 replications.

I have searched a couple websites and I just cant come to figure out how to create this sample any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: Based on your "oddly specific" percentage, you are looking to build a normally distributed dataset, check that out and ask a question showing what you have done and what didn't work. This community isn't here to write code for you, we are here to help you through a problem though. Cheers!

Comment: im sorry I tried writing the code myself and it wouldnt work I am a beginner and I think if i wouldve showed what ive tried it wouldve not made sense to you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Better make sure the homework police aren't patrolling...?* Plus you have not provided any code, but I'm feeling generous, so this may help you out:

```
prisoners <- sample(x = 1:0, size = 404638, prob = c(0.678, 1 - 0.678), replace = TRUE)
prop.table(table(prisoners))
# prisoners
#         0         1 
# 0.3225772 0.6774228 

boot_samples <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) sample(prisoners, replace = TRUE))
# > str(boot_samples)
# List of 1000
# $ : int [1:404638] 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
# $ : int [1:404638] 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ : int [1:404638] 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ : int [1:404638] 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 ...
# $ : int [1:404638] 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
# $ : int [1:404638] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
# ... and many more ...
```